# Помогите исправить синтаксическую ошибку cv.smooth

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.imshow("perv",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
img1=img
cv2.Smooth(img,img1,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3)
```

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Smooth'

Comment: Это не синтаксическая ошибка. Это отсутсвие в пакете `cv2` имени `Smooth`. И это какая-то путаница с `cv` и `cv2` или так и задумано?

Comment: как оказалось, smooth больше в cv2 нет(
@mkkik

Comment: Есть Сглаживание изображений (Smoothing Images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации сказано так:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
```

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html

Comment: все правильно - Гауссова фильтрация.